# How to Get user info from different domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

How to Get user info from different domain.
Get-ADUser -Identity username work with same domain1 but i want to know user info from different child Domain

Comment: doesn't get-aduser have a domain opton also?

Comment: This should really be tagged as Powershell and ActiveDirectory.

Answer (score 2):

I typed `Get-Help Get-ADUser -Full` and found the following:

> ```
> -Server <string>
>     Specifies the Active Directory Domain Services instance to connect to, by providing one of the following values
>      for a corresponding domain name or directory server. The service may be any of the following:  Active Director
>     y Lightweight Domain Services, Active Directory Domain Services or Active Directory Snapshot instance.
>     Domain name values:
>       Fully qualified domain name
>         Examples: corp.contoso.com
>       NetBIOS name
>         Example: CORP
>
>     Directory server values:
>       Fully qualified directory server name
>         Example: corp-DC12.corp.contoso.com
>       NetBIOS name
>         Example: corp-DC12
>       Fully qualified directory server name and port
>         Example: corp-DC12.corp.contoso.com:3268
>
>     The default value for the Server parameter is determined by one of the following methods in the order that they
>      are listed:
>       -By using Server value from objects passed through the pipeline.
>       -By using the server information associated with the Active Directory PowerShell provider drive, when running
>      under that drive.
>       -By using the domain of the computer running Powershell.
>
>     The following example shows how to specify a full qualified domain name as the parameter value.
>       -Server "corp.contoso.com"
>
>     Required?                    false
>     Position?                    named
>     Default value
>     Accept pipeline input?       false
>     Accept wildcard characters?  false
> ```

Is this what you're looking for??

Comment: I have gone throw following syntex but i believe due to Active Directory Web Services not running it has no result (Get-ADgroupMember -Identity "DL Name" | Get-ADUser -Server "DomainA" | Set-ADUser -Manager "Manager name" ) , error that comes up (Get-ADUser " Unable to contact the server. this may be because this server no exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the active directory web services running)...

Comment: You have a logic problem in that query. You querying the current domain for Get-ADgroupMember -Identity "DL Name" the other domain for Get-ADUser -Server "DomainA"  and then the first again for Set-ADUser -Manager "Manager name" )  you need to use -server for all the requests.